# Tryning to get the right information from mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to call the correct mysql information.

In my first query, I check if the order is available and take the post_id so I can make a SELECT that includes all post_id's for my while.

In the first query is there many post_id's so I need to connecte tto many id's

An example that does not work but explain what I mean:

```
  $query103 = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM `$v1`.`wpd2_posts` 
           where ID='order_id1' and ID='order_id2' and ID='order_id3' 
  ") or die(mysqli_error($conn));
```

The $orderidtilsoog can be more IDs and not just 1

Hope you understand me

The is the completaly code:

```
 $query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM `$v1`.`wpd2_postmeta` where meta_value='$emailconvert' ORDER BY meta_id ") or die(mysqli_error($conn));    


           echo "Kunden er fundet og ligger på https://v1.com";     

                while($row55 = mysqli_fetch_array($query))  {

                    $orderidtilsoog = $row55['post_id']. ",";

                    echo $orderidtilsoog;

       if(mysqli_num_rows($query) == '0') {

            }else{  

            $query103 = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM `$v1`.`wpd2_posts` where ID
      IN ('$orderidtilsoog')  ") or die(mysqli_error($conn));

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `SELECT * FROM $v1.wpd2_posts where ID IN('$orderidtilsoog')`

Comment: Yes it works but it still takes it 1 in this case there are 2 rows of post_id's i need to find

Comment: $orderidtilsoog = "id1" and "id2"

Comment: The query give only 1 one result ... but the orderidtilsoog = row 3 post_id's